# How to check which user is positioned in a directory on linux terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, ssh

yesterday i was shown that i can't unmount a mounted partition (like /media/test or /mnt/test) if someone is using the terminal in that directory (maybe in ssh connection).

he used a command that listed the user on that directory with pid of process in order to `kill` the `pid` and `unmount` the partitions.

I don't remember the command, could you help me?

ty

Comment: `lsof` or `fuser`? Your question should be moved to [Super User](http://superuser.com/tour).

Comment: lsof is the one, ty man! :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This one works nice: 
`lsof | grep '^bash.*cwd'`

Comment: What if the offending process isn't bash?

Comment: @Kenster Then you can use `lsof | grep '^[[:alnum:]]*[[:space:]]*[[:alnum:]]*[[:space:]]*[[:alnum:]]*[[:space:]]*cwd'` of course.